# Center text around certain position using overpic

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, parbox, overpic

I am using the overpic package to place text inside of a figure.
For using line breaks inside a `put` command I use `parbox` (see example code).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{overpic}[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\put(56,47){\parbox{10cm}{some\newline too long text}}
\end{overpic}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Using this code, the text is aligned left at the specified position of the `put` command.
How can I center the text around the specified position in the `put` command so that in the example code "some" should appear somewhere above "long"? Note that using `centering` centers the text around the middle of the figure which is not what I want.

Comment: `\centering some\par` instead of the `\newline`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your questions seems to have 2 components to it:

1. Centering the various lines of text relative to each other, and
2. Centering the block of text relative to the `\put` position.

For #1, I choose to use a stack, which also helps with #2, where I place the stack in a zero-width `\makebox`.

The MWE, where I also place a red dot at the same location, so that we can see that these `\put`s are centered about the `\put` point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{overpic}[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\put(56,47){\makebox[0pt]{\Centerstack{some\\ too long text}}}
\put(56,47){\makebox[0pt]{\Huge\textcolor{red}{.}}}
\end{overpic}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I might also suggest the alternative of using a `\stackinset` instead of an `overpic`.  The horizontal alignment of `l`, `c`, `r` (argument 1) and the vertical alignment of `t`, `c`, `b` (argument 3) non only tell where on the background image to use as the alignment reference, but also where on the inset to use as the reference.  Thus the use of `c` for both of these will guarantee that the center of the inset is placed relative to the center of the image, at the offsets provided.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\stackinset{c}{6pt}{c}{12pt}{\Centerstack{some\\too long text}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simple and complex. Simple is with `tabular`, complex is with `varwidth`.

The bullet is just to show the reference point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\begin{document}

\begin{overpic}[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\put(56,47){\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}some\\too long text\end{tabular}}
\put(56,47){\textbullet}
\end{overpic}

\bigskip

\begin{overpic}[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\put(56,47){\begin{varwidth}{10cm}\centering some\\too long text\end{varwidth}}
\put(56,47){\textbullet}
\end{overpic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to make the given coordinates the center of the added text, enclose it in `\makebox(0,0){...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\begin{document}

\begin{overpic}[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\put(56,47){\makebox(0,0){\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}some\\too long text\end{tabular}}}
\put(56,47){\makebox(0,0){\textbullet}}
\end{overpic}

\bigskip

\begin{overpic}[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\put(56,47){\makebox(0,0){\begin{varwidth}{10cm}\centering some\\too long text\end{varwidth}}}
\put(56,47){\makebox(0,0){\textbullet}}
\end{overpic}

\end{document}
```

[image]